# How to select a class in div, ul, li and a tag with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have html like this :

```
<div id="bangunan-light-pagination" class="pagination" >
<ul>
<li><a href="#page-1" class="page-link prev">Prev</a></li>
<li><a href="#page-1" class="page-link">1</a></li>
<li class="active"><span class="current">2</span></li>
<li class="active"><span class="current next">Next</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And Jquery like this (**jquery-1.7.2.min.js**):

```
$("#bangunan-light-pagination .page-link").live('click',function(){
alert('This is Me');
});
```

I have been tested it..but Jquery is not running. alert is not show.
How is the right syntax for showing the alert when i click which one a tag?

For knowing ul tag is added automatic with "jquery pagination". in default my html script just fill :

```
<div id="bangunan-light-pagination" class="pagination"></div>
```

Thanks.
Best Regards.

Comment: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed in newer versions of jquery (version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9), you could use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: What is the correct selector if i use .on(). Please show it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.live()` is deprecated as of v 1.7 and removed as of v 1.9. Use `.on()` instead:

```
$("#bangunan-light-pagination").on('click', ".page-link", function(){
   alert('This is Me');
});
```

Also as Marcel Gwerder pointed out you want to delegate the event listener to the parent, so notice the placement of `.page-link`:

```
$("#bangunan-light-pagination").on('click', ".page-link", function(){
```

instead of

```
$("#bangunan-light-pagination .page-link").on('click',function(){
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8wbhpv4w/1/)

Comment: Correct, your example though is not really the equivalent to `live` - missing delegation.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder right, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't even look past the `.live()`

Comment: I have change .live() with .on() but it is still not show the alert.

Comment: @ZAJ make sure your JS is placed at the bottom of the page so it loads after the HTML/CSS does, or use `$(document).ready(function(){ //code here});`

Comment: I have placed my JS at the bottom of page.i have test your fiddle and it is running well. I'm sorry i am just add more description in my question above.Please help me.

Comment: @ZAJ if you need more help I suggest you post a new question. If my answer has answered your original question please check it off as resolved and open a new question for additional help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bangunan-light-pagination").on('click', ".page-link", function(){
   alert('This is Me');
});
```